# Xbox One controller Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: bluetooth, input-devices, peripherals, xbox-one

What are the necessary steps to connect a wireless Xbox One controller with Ubuntu 18.04?

When I try to connect the Xbox sign only blinks but when I try to connect with a cable it works in an instant. I've tried to follow the old suggestion that surrounds Xbox 360 controller and Ubuntu 14/16 but it hasn't worked.

Comment: Remember to provide a link when referencing other questions/answers or solutions on other sites.

Answer (score 4):

Install `sysfsutils`

```
sudo apt install sysfsutils
```

Edit `/etc/sysfs.conf` (as root), add this line at the end of the file:

```
/module/bluetooth/parameters/disable_ertm=1
```

Save changes and restart

Reference:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2339212