# Xbox One wired controller on Ubuntu

Tags: input-devices, xbox-one

I tried to connect the Xbox One controller on Ubuntu 20.04. But as soon as I connect it, it only makes a vibration and the luminous button in the center does not light up. How can I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038001/xbox-one-controller-ubuntu-18-04